# Посмотреть или просмотреть

Tags: выбор-слов

Интересует несколько ситуаций:

- посмотреть/просмотреть профиль
- посмотреть/просмотреть метки
- посмотреть/просмотреть все вопросы и ответы

Как будет правильно? В частности интересует употребление в контексте ссылок, наблюдаемых на [странице профиля участника](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идёт о возможности, предоставляемой пользователю через ссылку, то естественнее "**посмотреть**", поскольку "*просмотреть*" означает ознакомление *со всем* имеющимся по ссылке материалом. Решение же "*просмотреть всё*" или только "*посмотреть* (интересующий аспект)" по ссылке может принять только сам пользователь.

Comment: Получается, что "посмотреть" это как более слабая форма "просмотреть"?

Comment: Да, это менее навязчивое предложение пользователю: оно не обязывает его _просмотреть_ подряд всё, что он найдёт. Но если он заинтересуется, то сможет и "просмотреть". А так он может посмотреть, если там что-либо его интересующее, окинуть взглядом содержимое, подумать: может стоит позже вернуться и "просмотреть" всё предлагаемое и т. п.

Comment: Текст в профиле поправил. Если заметите какие проблемы локализации, прошу писать на [Мету RuSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/)